# Using XMLHttpRequest for Mozilla Extension development

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox

I have some problems of calling a php file using Ajax in my 
Mozilla Extension.
The javascript (Ajax) and php are both located at directory /myextension/content, I am call the php using

```
function ajaxFunction(){
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', 'myphp.php', true);
    req.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {
      if (req.readyState == 4) {
         if(req.status == 200)
          alert(req.responseText);
         else
          alert("Error\n");
      }
    };
    req.send(null);
}
```

, and my php looks like

```
<? php 
echo "Server Received with thanks!";
?>
```

I keep geting "alert("Error\n");". 
Did i do anything wrong?

Comment: Are you actually running a PHP server?

Comment: Trying alerting something more useful than "Error", like the HTTP status code. That will give you some information. Alternatively, just try loading the page directly in a browser and see what you get.

Comment: Thanks, just read the page (https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_XMLHttpRequest) again, and missed "Non-HTTP synchronous request" example. So what i have is to read a file from local file system and status == 0 for success. What i really need is to make a request to the server from javascript in the extension and get the response, like Matt posted, there is no PHP server running at all. Is there another way that i can communicate with the back-end server in the extension development?

Comment: I have found http://code.google.com/p/json-xml-rpc/, hope this will serve my requests.

Answer (score 1):

Well formatted Ajax code for Firefox:

```
var URL="http://yourdomain.com/Work.php?val=Test";
var objXmlHttp = null;

try 
{
    objXmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
catch(e)
{return;}

objXmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if ((objXmlHttp.readyState == 4 || objXmlHttp.readyState == "complete") && objXmlHttp.status == 200)
    {
        //Write code for success
    }
    else if (objXmlHttp.status == 404)
    {
        //OnError
    }
    else 
    {
        //OnWait
    }
}

objXmlHttp.open("GET", URL, true);
objXmlHttp.send(null);
```